# React Native Android staging build crashes on startup

Tags: react-native

I have added 2 more buildTypes in my build.gradle file `staging` & `prestaging` alongside with `release`. When I build and run the `release` buildType it works fine on the real device, but when I build and run `staging` or `prestaging` builds both crashes on startup. The crash report on the device shows the following error:
[image]

*All the builds work without any issue on iOS*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `staging` and `prestaging` build failed because the bundle were not packaged correctly as the error says. This is because when building Android app react-native only add the bundle to the package if the `buildType` name contains the word `release`. The simple solution for this is to name the buildType's in such a way that the names contain the word **release**. I renamed the buildType's to `stagingRelease` and `prestagingRelease`.

Comment: Thank you so much! These "magic string" errors are a pain.